# Why is my node.js helloworld application on nitrous not working?

Tags: nitrous

I have read the tutorial many times. I copied the code and paste it. Still, there is no "Port 3000" under the "Preview" menu. The Preview URL is 404.

If I run `wget 127.0.0.1:3000`, the response message is ok. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the starter templates automatically expose ports, but it looks like the template you selected doesn't automatically expose ports for you.

You can click the "Configure Ports" item in the Preview Menu, then add port 3000 (make sure you tick the "Preview" checkbox):

https://community.nitrous.io/docs/port-configuration

Hope that helps!